# Json body for webservice functions with multiple parameters

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to do a post request which fails whenever I add a second parameter to the function.

This for example works with the following function:

```
public class Mock
{
     public String MyFirstValue { get; set; }
     public String MySecondValue { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ResponseDataDTO TestPost(Mock test)
{
     var response = new ResponseDataDTO();
     return response;
}
```

With the following body request:

```
{ 
   "MyFirstValue": "testvalue", 
   "MySecondValue": "testvalue" }
}
```

However when I add another parameter to this function, it does not work anymore because I'm not quite sure of how to construct the json:

```
[HttpPost]
public ResponseDataDTO TestPost(Mock test, Mock test2)
{
      var response = new ResponseDataDTO();
      return response;
}
```

My best guess of a body:

```
{ 
   "test": {
               "MyFirstValue": "testvalue", 
               "MySecondValue": "testvalue"
   }
   "test2": {
               "MyFirstValue": "testvalue2", 
               "MySecondValue": "testvalue2"
   }
}
```

I haven't had these problems before becuase I usually just have one object parameter which takes it all.

Another strange thing that I can't get to work is a method with only an integer parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ResponseDataDTO TestPostInteger(int test)
{
      var response = new ResponseDataDTO();
      return response;
}
```

With body:

```
{ 
   "test" : 1
}
```

This gives me a 404, it wont even find the method. If I put the parameter in URL instead, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response body can only bind to one object.

Having said that, one solution would be to `TestPost` takes in an array of `Mock`.  Like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ResponseDataDTO TestPost(Mock[] tests)
 { ... }
```

Json:

```
[
   {
       "MyFirstValue": "testvalue", 
       "MySecondValue": "testvalue"
   },
   {
       "MyFirstValue": "testvalue2", 
       "MySecondValue": "testvalue2"
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that it could only bind to one object.